Serialization in Kafka
If I serialize an object manually as a byte array before producing it in kafka will it be serialized internally by kafka again or the kafka's serialization will be skipped on receiving a byte array.
I have done message pack serialization, which is most optimized, I need to know whether my manual serialization is redundant and un-necessary, or this approach is actually useful.

I don't think it's redundant. Kafka is layer 4 so it's just a stream of bytes.

According to what is Msgpack most optimized over Protobuf, Avro, or others?

@OneCricketeer Msgpack is faster and more compact for lightweight, schema-less data. It avoids the overhead of Protobuf's descriptors and Avro's strict schemas. Great for quick, efficient serialization!

Curious if there are benchmarks for this?

I don't think it's redundant.
In kafka, Serializer/Deserializer must be specified. ByteArraySerializer (byte array serializer), StringSerializer (string serializer), and IntegerSerializer (integer serializer) are provided by default.
If you serialize an object manually as a byte array, ByteArraySerializer is a good choice. Your message won't be serialized internally by kafka again.
But you can custom Serializer by implementing
org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer

which is the best practice.
